# PHP INSERT Not working, possible bad array?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys im getting really stuck and could use some help,

I have a query that runs like this

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT TN,point,source FROM table LIMIT ".$_POST['cases']."");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Then in the while loop i am able to echo

```
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['0']." and ".$row['1']." and ".$row['2']."<br>";
```

And get the proper result for each $row['']

My problem is when adding these into the insert statement.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO assigned (TN,point,date1,dude,test,row,rows) VALUES (".$row['0'].",".$row['1'].",'$date','$df','$dx','$num',".$row['2'].")");
```

The only thing holding the queryback is the $row['2'], if i remove and make it '123' it will properly insert row 0 and 1 and the rest of the data. Ive tried almost all combination to get this to work and im having no luck.

Comment: Not strong with PHP, but I sure hope sprintf() sanitizes input

Comment: I'll just come out and say it's probably due to an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability, plus a serious case of cargo-cult programming. Combined with a total lack of any kind of error handling, perfect recipe for this kind of question.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: it does nothing. it's a useless call too, since there's no `%` placeholders in the target string.

Comment: @MarcB oh it's like python's format almost (conceptually)

Comment: @SterlingArcher: it's a direct equivalent of C's sprintf. Most of PHP is just a wrapper around equivalent underlying libc calls.

Comment: @SterlingArcher In the best case, `sprintf()` would cast strings to integer 0 with `%i, %u` placeholders and avoid some very specific types of injection, but that's nothing more than a side effect.

Comment: What type and length is your column rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add single quotation marks around $row['2'], like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO assigned (TN,point,date1,dude,test,row,rows) VALUES (".$row['0'].",".$row['1'].",'$date','$df','$dx','$num','".$row['2']."')");
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @raidenace Using a deprecated function is usually a bad practice, no matter the question asked. I believe that answers should mention these issues (at least when it's possible to do so), even if they seem irrelevant.

Comment: Alex Thanks a million!!! havnt got a clue why that works but it does.. and StathisG, Its an update for app on an old server. Thanks Guys For all the help.